# Call Javascript Function After Saving Calendar Item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, client-object-model

I am having a script as below:-

```
function getColorValue(aId,atitle) {
try{
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Item type');
        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(parseInt(aId));
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {            
            var listItem = oListItem;
            var colorname = listItem.get_item('Color_x0020_Name');
            if (typeof colorname != 'undefined') {
                if (colorname != null) {
                    $("div[title$='" + atitle + "']").css("background-color", colorname);
                }
            }
        }, onColorQueryFail);
}
catch(e){

}
}
```

I need to call this script each time after a SharePoint Calendar Item is created.

Can anyone help?